# Capture iphone network packet

Tags: networking, tcp, wifi, packet

I want to capture iphone apps network data traffic and packet. Do you have any idea to let me be possible? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about wifi, just use [`tcpdump(1)`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/tcpdump.1.html) on your computer wireless interface. Cellular network, on the other hand, is point-to-point and is not that easy.